# Using `ARRAYFORMULA` with `FILTER` in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some entries against days of the year:
[image: Entries for days of the year]

I want to state the average of these entries for every week (hence the week helper column in Column A).

Normally to do this I would use `FILTER`:

```
AVERAGE(FILTER(C:C, A:A = A1 ) ))
```

Where A1 is the week number against which I would like to place the average (assume that this is on another tab and correctly referencing the data).

This works for a single cell, and if I drag the formula down manually. However, I want it to update automatically, but I cannot use `ARRAYFORMULA` with `FILTER`. I am not sure of the solution: the other questions on SO can be solved more easily as they do not require multiple rows to be returned. I do, so I cannot use `VLOOKUP`, which would solve the problem.

Comment: Could you share a sample of the Sheets? It would be helpful to get a proper vision on how the formulas are interacting with each other. Rembember to sanitaze all sensible data.

Comment: Thank you, pls see here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jw98sW3MhdAAhlAA3-PUwirA83_x_7I12654uXmaZgI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a new cell, on a brand new tab, try this assuming the tab name with the data is "Sheet1":

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:C,"select A,AVG(C) where A<>'' group by A")
```

Here is a [good resource](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/) on QUERY().

Comment: Thanks. I played with this and it turns out that because my week column is itself produced through an `ARRAYFORMULA`, it won't show up in a `QUERY`. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @LoneWallaby That shouldn't matter, though it might matter if column A is a number rather than the text it looks like....  Try this instead:

=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:C,"select A,AVG(C) where A is not null group by A")

Comment: I think in fact the way I am constructing the week column is making the values null. See here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jw98sW3MhdAAhlAA3-PUwirA83_x_7I12654uXmaZgI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: aha! it was some cond formatting and the way you wrote the Arrayformula that was hiding the issue. I've modified the array for the week and eliminated the Cond. Formatting.  Formula now works fine.